controlling brightness on wayland & dual monitors
I had a script that used xrandr to dim all monitors.  It broke on wayland. There are some command line options, but I don't want to recode everything. Ubuntu 22.04 recognizes the keyboard Fn-keys for brighter/darker, but only for my laptop display. Can someone please save me from another hour of coding?
The question: is there any GUI or simple tool to control brightness and not break redshift/night-light for multiple monitors?
Thanks a lot!
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
PS:
gammastep & xandr break on wayland;
brightnessctl & clight do not affect my external monitor
